# Can warlock spell slots be used to cast above warlock casting level when multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, spellcasting

One of my players is considering multiclassing warlock/cleric. I have not played warlocks or had other players use them so I am looking into the casting mechanics. After looking at other threads I think I have the idea down. Something like a warlock 1/cleric 5 would have the cantrips and 1 warlock slot that can cast at first level and the cleric would provide up to 3rd level spell slots. my confusion comes from

> Pact Magic:
> If you have both the spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

so they would be able to cast warlock spells up to 3rd level with the cleric 3rd level slot, as evident from answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120421/can-i-cast-a-warlock-spell-with-another-higher-spell-slot-from-a-different-mul), but would they also be **able to cast fireball (in the case of a light domain cleric) using their warlock slot but doing so at 1st level?** If so how would this translate to an end game build? would the cleric then have the equivalent to 2 9th level slots?

I am assuming this does not work this way and the initial build listed essentially just has a slightly expanded spell list and an extra 1st level slot that comes back on a short rest, but I just want to make sure I am not missing something so I can explain this fully in the future.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey I'm unsure if this is a duplicate. The question whether you can cast the fireball at level 1 seems to not be covered by the answers to the other question.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't seem to answer the question *"would they also be able to cast fireball (in the case of a light domain cleric) using their warlock slot but doing so at 1st level?"*. (Answer should be pretty clear though, 1st level slot vs 3rd level spell.)

Comment: Sorry about the mess the dupe closing, but unless I'm missing something I believe *this* question is the same as yours. It uses sorcerer and 4th level spells instead of cleric and a 3rd, but that should be immaterial. Do give word if there's something in your question it doesn't resolve, and we'll see what needs to be done to help (there are a lot questions around posted around this, so you might well find it by searching or browsing the linked and related questions).

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!